# IComparer based on property of an interface

Tags: c#, interface, icomparer

I have created a ***class Car*** that derives form the ***abstract class TransportMeans*** and implements an ***interface PrivateMeans*** which contains only one property:

```
interface PrivateMean 
{
int capacity { set; get; }
}
```

I want to implement a class thet sorts the objects of the ***class Car*** according to the property capacity. I want to do this by the use of the ***interface IComparer***.

However, when I declare an additonal ***class CarComparer*** as follows:

```
public class CarComparer : IComparer<Car>
{

    int IComparer<Car>.Comparer(Car obj1, Car obj2)
    {
        PrivateMean t1 = (PrivateMean)obj1;
        PrivateMean t2 = (PrivateMean)obj2;


        if (t1 != null && t2 != null)
        {
            if (t1.capacity >= t2.capacity)
                return 1;
            else return -1;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Some Parameter is not a Car!");
    }
}
```

I receive the error :

**Error 1   'MeansOfTransport.CarComparer' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer.Compare(MeansOfTransport.Car, MeansOfTransport.Car)'.**

What is the problem?

Furthermore I am not allowed to use ***IComparer*** without a type definition (Car). Why?

Comment: `IComparer` and `IComparer<T>` are different interfaces.  The text of your question mentions one, while the code uses the other.  If you want to use the non-templated version `IComparer`, you need to remove `<Car>` where you state the implemented interfaces, from where you implement the interface, and change the type parameters in the implementation to `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
int IComparer<Car>.Comparer(Car obj1, Car obj2)
```

You probably meant

```
int IComparer<Car>.Compare(Car obj1, Car obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

- You need to implement a `Compare` method, but yours is called `Comparer`
- The method you are implementing is `public`, so yours should be too. Currently your method has no access modifier, so it will default to `internal`.